# SAP UI5 XML View Tiles Icon not working

Tags: tiles, sapui5

I have a XML View:

```
<mvc:View height="100%" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="my.own.controller">
<App>
    <Page showHeader="false" enableScrolling="false">
        <TileContainer id="container" tileDelete="handleTileDelete" tiles="{/TileCollection}">
            <StandardTile icon="sap-icon://{icon}" number="{number}" title="{title}" info="{info}" infoState="Success" />
        </TileContainer>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    </Page>
</App>
```

And I have a js:

```
function initialLoad(){

// create some dummy JSON data
var data = {
        "TileCollection" : [{
                                "icon":"history",
                                "number":"3",
                                "title" : "Project History",
                                "info": "click to view",
                                "infoState" : "Success"
                            }]
};

// instantiate the View
sap.ui.localResources("XMLViews");
var app = new sap.m.App({initialPage:"welcome"});
var myView  = sap.ui.xmlview({id:"welcome", viewName:"XMLViews/welcome"});
app.addPage(myView);

// create a Model and assign it to the View
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData(data);
myView.setModel(oModel);

// put the View onto the screen
myView.placeAt("content");}
```

The problem is the icon is not showing up. If I hard code in my XML view:

```
icon="sap-icon://history"
```

Then the icon is showing up correctly.

I am stuck with this problem for one day and I appreciate if you could give me some hint!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Way of binding data to the `icon` property is incorrect. it should be in this way.

```
icon="{icon}"
```

**Instead make the change in your json as below:**

```
var data = {
        "TileCollection" : [{
                                "icon":"sap-icon://history", 
                                "number":"3",
                                "title" : "Project History",
                                "info": "click to view",
                                "infoState" : "Success"
                            }]
};
```

I think this will work.

Comment: Check https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/21ea0ea94614480d9a910b2e93431291.html